# Why do I get different result when using multithreading to ping an IP segment?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to check which IP(s) is/are available in a segment.

```
public class Test {
       static volatile int cnt; 
       public static void main(String[] s) throws InterruptedException{
              int i;
              for(i=1;i<256;i++){
                     PING ping = new PING(i);
                     Thread t = new Thread(ping);
                     t.start();
              }
              Thread.sleep(200);
              System.out.println("\ncnt: "+cnt);
       }

       static class PING implements Runnable{
              private int i;
              private String ip = "172.20.1.";
              private String host;
              PING(int i){
                     this.i = i;
              }

              public void run() {
                     host = ip + i;
                     try {

                           if(InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(200)){
                                  cnt++;
                                  System.out.print(i+", ");
                           }

                     } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                     }
              } 
       }
}
```

I know there are 7 IPs available and the expected result is:

```
1, 2, 24, 79, 81, 254, 60,
cnt: 7
```

However, I got 5 or 6 IPs more frequently than 7 during my test, and sometimes I got below result(6 IPs but `cnt` is 5):

```
24, 79, 81, 2, 1, 60,
cnt: 5
```

Can anyone tell me the reason? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are printing your thread result simply after 200ms rather than waiting for them all to be complete

Comment: Your main thread does not synchronize with the other threads. Also some of the threads probably do not receive answer within 200ms.

Comment: @BalázsNemes I checked that each IP will respond within 10 ms(by `ping 172.20.1.x -w 10`). On the other hand, I change the timeout value to 2000 `isReachable(2000)` but there's no difference. And could you give some hints how to synchronize in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

You assume that your thread will be finished within 200ms. If the server's answer takes longer, you will not see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need a more reliable way to determine when your threads finish, here is a very simple check:

I created another int that keeps track of how many threads are complete and when they are all done it prints your result. (Each thread calls `complete()` when it is done)

```
public class Test {
       static volatile int cnt; 
       static volatile int finished = 0;
       public static void main(String[] s) throws InterruptedException{
              int i;
              for(i=1;i<256;i++){
                     PING ping = new PING(i);
                     Thread t = new Thread(ping);
                     t.start();
              }
       }

       public static void complete() {
           finished++;
           if(finished >= 256) {
              System.out.println("\ncnt: "+cnt);
           }
       }

       static class PING implements Runnable{
              private int i;
              private String ip = "172.20.1.";
              private String host;
              PING(int i){
                     this.i = i;
              }

              public void run() {
                     host = ip + i;
                     try {

                           if(InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(200)){
                                  cnt++;
                                  System.out.print(i+", ");
                           }

                     } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     complete();
              } 
       }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But it seems no stable. I mean, it's still possible to get 5, 6 or 7 IPs by my test. I think, calling `complete()` only stores the number of executions of the loop to `finished`, but how to guarantee each thread has finished?

Comment: I am unfamiliar is the specifics of `InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(200)` but from the [javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)) I can't confirm if this is blocking or not - could you confirm that `isReachable` will block until it succeeds or reaches the timeout?

Comment: Also another note, you may need to increase your timeout or change your method of pinging, as noted from this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555549/java-inetaddress-isreachable-timeout

Comment: with `for(i =1;i<3;i++)` I ping 2 IPs(only one is reachable) with the same code but  `try` part being changed to `try {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+System.currentTimeMillis());
    if(InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(2000)) {
     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+System.currentTimeMillis());
    }     
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+System.currentTimeMillis());        
   }` then get `Thread-01499781381771
Thread-11499781381771
Thread-01499781381858
Thread-01499781381858
Thread-11499781383443`.

Comment: So I guess it will block until it succeeds(Thread - 0) or reaches the timeout(Thread -1, but the time gap is less than 2000ms?)

Comment: Well I would assume it can fail / succeed in less than 2000ms if the conditions are met. However this is a bit out of my realm of knowledge so I'm not sure I can help you much more. (No access to a computer for now)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `Callable<T>` and `Future<V>` see my example below:

```
public class PingTest {

  static class PING implements Callable<String>{
    private int i;
    private String ip = "172.20.1.";
    private String host;
    PING(int i){
      this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
      host = ip + i;
      try {

        if(InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(200)){
          return  i+", ";
        }else{
          return "not reachable";
        }

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return "not reachable";
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] s) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    List<Future<String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(255);
    for(int i=1;i<256;i++) {
      results.add(executor.submit(new PING(i)));
    }
    //Synchronization starts here
    int numberOfFinishedThreads;
    {
      Thread.sleep(100);
      numberOfFinishedThreads = 0;
      for(Future<String> result : results){
        if(result.isDone()){
          numberOfFinishedThreads++;
        }
      }
    }while(numberOfFinishedThreads < 255);
    //Here we are synchronized
    int numberOfReachable = 0;
    for(Future<String> result : results){
      if(! result.get().equals("not reachable")){
        System.out.print(result.get());
        numberOfReachable++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("\ncnt: " + numberOfFinishedThreads);
  }

}
```

The above code is not tested, but I hope it will work :). Here you can find a good guide about Java concurency:
http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/

Comment: Well, embarrassedly this is a little complicated and beyond my current knowledge scope in Java ;(. Maybe I should learn something from the link you posted first. Thanks!